# Check presence of a hostname under custom port in known_hosts

Tags: ssh, hostname, ssh-keygen

I need to add a check if the hostname is already present in the `known_hosts` file.

Normally I would do something like that:

```
ssh-keygen -H -F hostname
```

However, that does not seem to work for me in this particular case. I connect to the host using port 2102, like that:

```
ssh user@myhost -p 2102
```

I was asked to add the hostname to the `known_hosts` file, I say yes. After that I run `ssh-keygen -H -F myhost` but receive empty result.

To make the matter worse, the `known_hosts` is hashed.

That works perfectly with port 22, so if I login to `ssh user@myotherhost`, save the known host and run `ssh-keygen -H -F myotherhost` I receive the exact line from the file.

So, how can I adjust the command to work with port 2102?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this format: `[hostname]:2121`, as it is stored in the `known_hosts` file (note, you need to use the square brackets!):

```
ssh-keygen -H -F "[hostname]:2121"
```

Proof of concept (transcript of my minimal test case):

```
$ echo "[hostname]:2121 ssh-rsa AAA...==" > known_hosts
$ ssh-keygen -Hf known_hosts 
known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as known_hosts.old
WARNING: known_hosts.old contains unhashed entries
Delete this file to ensure privacy of hostnames
$ ssh-keygen -H -F "[hostname]:2121" -f known_hosts
|1|R21497dX9jN052A92GSoVFbuTPM=|lRtIr6O564EaFG0SsIulNAWpcrM= ssh-rsa AAA...==
```

You might need to use IP address instead of hostname, but it should generally work.